# Pulling result and fixture data into an android application

Tags: android

I am currently designing a mobile application for a sports organisation that needs to display player information, results and upcoming fixtures, the organisation is currently using sporty hq to display all of this information and I was curious if anyone has any ideas on how to pull this data into my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They have already **implemented** the API](https://www.sportyhq.com/features/api) . So, just register to get a token and pass parameters.

Following is a PHP sample but you can send the same parameters in Android via a network library such as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) .

[image]